# Can i use Babel Require Hook in production for ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I have a node app that uses ES6. I'm using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) for transpiling.
As far as i understand use a build system like Gulp for example or use the [require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_register) .
The Require Hook approach seems appealing to me since i will be able to keep my source files in ES6 but still execute them using `node server.js` without the use of some build system.

This seems extremely useful for develop at least, my main concerns is about the use of this approach in production.

- Does it have any penalty hit every time that a user makes a request ?
- How this works exactly ?

For context i'm using it with an Express app.

Comment: FWIW, the "build system" can be as simple as running `babel src/ --out-dir dist/`. This will convert all files in `src/` and save them in `dist/`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does it have any penalty hit every time that a user makes a request ?

No, not in the sense that it would have to re-transpile the code on every request.

> How this works exactly ?

The require hook basically hi-jacks all subsequent calls to `require()`, and performs the ES6->ES5 transpiling prior to that module being executed.

I've been using the babel require hook in production for awhile now (with moderate traffic levels -- peak traffic in the mid-hundreds req/sec range), and it's never been an issue.

Comment: So basically transpile it the first time and caches it or something like that ?

Comment: Sort of (but not really). Even without babel in the mix at all, any given module only gets executed once. Obviously if it were to export a function or something, that function could be executed any number of times, but the module itself only gets evaluated a single time at the point that it gets required for the first time. Introducing babel into the mix doesn't change that behavior, it simply performs a transpilation before that one-time evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: @jmar777 The require hook does have its own cache based on file mtimes.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Just saw your comment (half a year later). And yes, Babel does cache the transpiled versions of modules to speed up restarts during the development lifecycle, but that cache is never consulted again after the module has been transpiled (or fetched from cache) when it's initially `require()`'d. I.e., it's completely orthogonal to per-request performance concerns.